# Creating factor variables 'weekend' and 'weekday' from date

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have the following dataframe. This is just the head and the dates span over a period of 2 months. My question is how can I create a new factor variable in the dataframe with two levels, "weekday" and "weekend", indicating whether a given date is a weekday or weekend day?

```
    steps        date      interval
1 37.3826  2012-10-01             0
2 37.3826  2012-10-01             5
3 37.3826  2012-10-01            10
4 37.3826  2012-10-01            15
5 37.3826  2012-10-01            20
6 37.3826  2012-10-01            25
```

Comment: @akrun: new users need minimum 15 rep to accept answers

Comment: @smci 15 rep is for upvoting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `base R`

```
df1$date <- as.Date(df1$date)
#create a vector of weekdays
weekdays1 <- c('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday')
#Use `%in%` and `weekdays` to create a logical vector
#convert to `factor` and specify the `levels/labels`
df1$wDay <- factor((weekdays(df1$date) %in% weekdays1), 
         levels=c(FALSE, TRUE), labels=c('weekend', 'weekday') 
#Or
df1$wDay <- c('weekend', 'weekday')[(weekdays(df1$date) %in% weekdays1)+1L]
```

Or `isWeekday`, `isWeekend` from `timeDate`.  We can specify the `weekdays` with `wday` argument.  It returns a logical vector, and if we need to convert to strings that can be possible as showed above.

```
library(timeDate)
isWeekday(df1$date, wday=1:5)
```

Comment: Thanks akrun! It works. I thought it would be if(date == "Saturday" or date == "Sunday") {c("weekend")} else {c("weekday")} but it didn't work, your code is clean and easy to understand.

Comment: But why +1L in the factor function ? I don't get it. It seems not working when I remove the +1L.

Comment: @黄小立 `(weekdays(df1$date) %in% weekdays1)` returns a logical vector.  You can either use `ifelse(weekdays(df1$date) %in% weekdays1, 'weekday', 'weekend')` or add `1` to the logical vector to coerce the logical vector to numeric `1, 2` for `FALSE, TRUE` and use that as numeric index or convert to `factor`.  Using with `factor`, it should also work without `+1L` if you specify the levels as `c(FALSE, TRUE)` i.e. `factor((weekdays(df1$date) %in% weekdays1), levels=c(FALSE, TRUE), labels=c('weekend', 'weekday'))`

Comment: thanks akrun, the levels=c(FALSE, TRUE) is more clear I think.

Answer (score 6):

What about this:

```
activity$week <- ifelse(weekdays(activity$date) %in% c("Saturday", "Sunday"), "weekend", "weekday")
```

Answer (score 3):

using package `chron`, and assuming that your data.frame is called `df`:

```
df$weekend = chron::is.weekend(df$date)
```

the result is a column of boolean, TRUE when the date is in weekend (better to manipulate booleans here than strings)

Answer (score 2):

Just thought I'd add a slightly more efficient answer using base, and taking advantage of the fact that both Saturday and Sunday are the only days starting with an "S":

`df$Weekend <- grepl("S.+",weekdays(df$date))`